# Firebase security rules with users collection for Signin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a "**users**" collection to store some user data such as city, age, etc. I use firebase Authentication as a document key.

An example path is: `/users/ZXHSGdhjfdfwd`

I want users to read-only their data while signup/signin. So I have a rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /posts/{post}/{document=**}{
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, and rules monitors show an error. As a result, users cannot sign in as I read users' collections as part of the sign-in process.

When I remove userId and change the rule to:

```
match /users/{userId} {
      allow read:  if (request.auth != null);
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

It works, however, does that mean that userID from firestore (key) and auth.uid does not match, or one of them is null?

This is a pretty standard rule. Why is it not working?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the exact, minimal code we can run against these rules to reproduce the problem you're having?

Comment: Is this `ZXHSGdhjfdfwd` the UID that comes from authentication? Or is it generated by you?

Comment: @AlexMamo, this is the uid coming from firebase auth.

Comment: I doubt it, as it's too short. The UID should contain 28 characters. Are you sure you are not modifying it in your application code?

Comment: @levye , Could you share a reproducible code of how you add the data to your `users` collection? If possible, include how you are passing the authentication UID to Firestore.